# How to divide values of first column into two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

| Total | Male | Female |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | NAN | NAN |
| 45 | 21 | 24 |
| 36 | NAN | NAN |
| 50 | NAN | NAN |

This is my dataframe with 3 columns in pandas. The "Male" and "Female" columns contains null values.

So, is there any method to divide each value of "Total" and feed into respective "Male" and "Female" rows?

My desired output would be this:

| Total | Male | Female |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 12 | 12 |
| 45 | 21 | 24 |
| 36 | 18 | 18 |
| 50 | 25 | 25 |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good example of `df.mask`:

```
v = df['Total'].div(2)
df[['Male','Female']] = df[['Male','Female']].mask(df.isna(),v,axis=0)
#or for new df: out = df.assign(**df[['Male','Female']].mask(df.isna(),v,axis=0))
```

---

```
   Total Male Female
0     24   12     12
1     45   21     24
2     36   18     18
3     50   25     25
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to divide `Total` by 2 then [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) across rows to fill the missing values:

```
cols = ['Male', 'Female']
df[cols] = df.assign(Total=df['Total'] / 2).ffill(axis=1)[cols]
```

Or by creating a new DataFrame to use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with. In case there are rows with some NaN and some valid values where `ffill` may propagate incorrect values:

```
cols = ['Male', 'Female']
x = df['Total'] / 2
df = df.fillna(pd.DataFrame({c: x for c in cols}))
```

`df`:

```
   Total  Male  Female
0     24  12.0    12.0
1     45  21.0    24.0
2     36  18.0    18.0
3     50  25.0    25.0
```

---

Setup:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Total': [24, 45, 36, 50],
    'Male': [np.nan, 21, np.nan, np.nan],
    'Female': [np.nan, 24, np.nan, np.nan]
})
```

Comment: But this would divide the second row value 45 too , right.
I just want it for Nan values.
so i should select the nan rows first and then go for this.Am i right?

Comment: It will divide all values but `ffill` will only replace `NaN`. Notice row two the values are unchanged.